# Debugging 32 bit application running in 64 bit environment

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg, sos

I have a 32 bit .Net 4.0 application running in a wow64 environment in a 64 bit machine.

The application encountered an error and I took a dump with 32 bit taskmanager present in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\taskmgr.exe

I am using a 32 bit Windebugger to analyze this dump. I loaded  the following dlls.

1).loadby sos CLR

2).load mscordacwks ( from the client machine).

But still I am not able to use SOS commands like `!clrstack,!threads` etc.

I get the error:
**Failed to load data access DLL, 0x80004005**

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that mscordacwks is not correctly loaded

### One way

Try:

```
.cordll -u -ve -lp <absolute-path-to-directory-where-client-mscordacwks-is-placed>
```

The correct output should be:

```
CLRDLL: Loaded DLL <your-path>\mscordacwks.dll
CLR DLL status: Loaded DLL <your-path>\mscordacwks.dll
```

If you see:

```
CLR DLL status: No load attempts
```

rename your mscordacwks to the name suggested by .cordll:

```
0:000> .cordll
CLR DLL status: ERROR: Unable to load DLL mscordacwks_x86_x86_2.0.50727.3625.dll, Win32 error 0n87
```

and add the path where renamed mscordacwks resides to symbols:

```
.sympath+ <your-path>
```

and try your SOS command.

### Other way

Get procdumpext.dll from Andrew Richard's skydrive : http://sdrv.ms/11C7S9c, load it into windbg (`.load procdumpext.dll`) and execute `!loadsos`.

Good luck! :)

Comment: .cordll does not show the name of mscordacwks. It shows as "no Load attempts"

Comment: and !threads for example? It should be something like:
CLRDLL: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscordacwks.dll:2.0.50727.5446 f:0
    doesn't match desired version 2.0.50727.3625 f:0
    CLRDLL: Unable to find mscordacwks_x86_x86_2.0.50727.3625.dll by mscorwks search

Comment: Also, which version of windbg are you using? In newer versions you may try `!analyse -v` and they should load the valid sos automatically.

Comment: The Skydrive link is broken. Do you have a copy of ProcDumpExt?

Comment: It seems this is now named PDE and available on https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=dae128bd454cf957&id=DAE128BD454CF957!7152&ithint=folder,zip&authkey=!ALq3LqMcfgs8JoM

Comment: @ThomasWeller have a look at netext.codeplex.com - I also wrote about it here: https://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2015/07/09/netext-sos-on-steroids/. It loads the valid SOS version automatically and adds interesting diagnostics commands as well

Comment: Actually I was looking for ProcDumpExt due to other features, not for a way of loading the correct version of SOS :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had the best results in case I didn't only get mscordacwks.dll but also sos.dll from the client machine. I even had SxS issues with those files, so getting the files from the default .NET framework directory was not helpful either. Therefore I created the [mscordacwks collector](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/download-mscordacwks-collector/) which gets all possible files for you.

However, you still need to find out which version to use. You can start by looking at the .NET framework version:

```
lm vm clr; *** .NET CLR 4
lm vm mscorwks; *** .NET CLR 2
lm vm coreclr; *** Silverlight
```

(In worst case, you have two different version of .NET loaded, in which case [you are out of luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229889/using-sos-in-a-dump-with-net-2-mscorwks-and-net-4-clr)).

Once you know the exact version, you can load SOS of that version by full path

```
.load c:\mypath\SOS_AMD64_AMD64_4.0.30319.18444.dll
```

Note that the collected versions of SOS.dll will also be renamed to avoid file name conflicts. For more convenience, you can create a copy and just rename it to SOS.dll.

If there are still any mscordacwks.dll issues, you can proceed as proposed by @lowleveldesign. The tool should already have renamed data access files appropriately. If you find any bug, feedback is welcome.