# How to use WinDbg SOS extension to debug a process with 2 .NET runtimes?

Tags: .net, windbg, sos

I'm debugging a process with .NET 2 and Silverlight 5.1 runtime at the same time using WinDbg SOS. Get the following error if I run any SOS command:

```
Failed to load data access DLL, 0x80004005
Verify that 1) you have a recent build of the debugger (6.2.14 or newer)
            2) the file mscordacwks.dll that matches your version of mscorwks.dll is 
                in the version directory
            3) or, if you are debugging a dump file, verify that the file 
                mscordacwks_<arch>_<arch>_<version>.dll is on your symbol path.
            4) you are debugging on the same architecture as the dump file.
                For example, an IA64 dump file must be debugged on an IA64
                machine.

You can also run the debugger command .cordll to control the debugger's
load of mscordacwks.dll.  .cordll -ve -u -l will do a verbose reload.
If that succeeds, the SOS command should work on retry.

If you are debugging a minidump, you need to make sure that your executable
path is pointing to mscorwks.dll as well.
```

The process is built by .NET 2, and I'm sure that I'm using the correct version of SOS. Just don't know why ilverlight is loaded into the process.  It will work well if I uninstall Silverlight from my computer completely.

Also I saw the post [Using SOS in a dump with .NET 2 (mscorwks) and .NET 4 (clr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229889/using-sos-in-a-dump-with-net-2-mscorwks-and-net-4-clr). When I tried  `.cordll -ve -u -l` I get the following result:

```
0:005> .cordll -ve -u -l
CLR DLL status: No load attempts
```

When I tried `.cordll -ve  -se -u -I 6d760000 -N` where 6d760000 is the start address of .NET 2 mscorwks.dll:

```
0:005>  .cordll -ve  -se -u -I 6d760000 -N
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll - 
NOTE: This code is not supported and may not work.
Do not report any problems you have.
CLR DLL status: No load attempts
  Test new CLR interfaces
```

I'm using Windbg 6.12. Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Can you try fixing the symbols (`.symfix X:\symbols`) and use the [newer version 6.3.9600](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/windbg-versions/) of WinDbg?

Comment: From where did you get the info that "Silverlight runtime" is loaded? I personally think you just loaded the wrong SOS. Please review http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2009/02/18/failed-to-load-data-access-dll-0x80004005-or-what-is-mscordacwks-dll.aspx

Comment: The application I debug is built on .NET 2 for sure. I'm using SOS.dll for .NET 2 to debug it. As I said, it will work well if I uninstall silver light from my computer. When I'm checking the loaded modules, I find that coreclr.dll from silver light folder is loaded. It looks like the runtime of the silver light will be loaded into the process as long as it's installed. And the silver light is installed automatically because some other apps depend on it.